# Create GIF from images in a Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

My question is easy: Is it possible to create an animated GIF file from a Windows Phone app (7.8 or 8, or both) using C# ?

I searched on the internet for this and I found these tutorials:
http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/rick/archive/2005/05/10/3830.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11505/NGif-Animated-GIF-Encoder-for-NET

They are really cool and work perfectly for desktop app, but I can't make them work on a Windows Phone app, many classes are unavailable and I can't find a workaround. Is it really impossible to create a GIF file from images on a Windows Phone ? Is it due to the devices limitations ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to create the file, so you can store it or send it, or just to display it? If it is for display purposes, don't try to create an animated gif. Just create individual images and use an animation to display them.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i don't know how far Ill be able to help. But if you are facing limitations in displaying a gif Image then you can use a nuget package named image tools

[Blog for Image tools](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/show-gif-images-in-windows-phone-7-1/)

And on the other hand if you want to display a number of images then I can suggest a work around. But it will be app specific.

use `storyboards` or `timers` to continiously animate an Image object or a Grid back ground.

Creating an image I guess is not possible due to device limitation

still if you have  a sprite image

then you can use

```
 <ImageBrush.Transform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="-380" Y="200" x:Name="tfDieImage"></TranslateTransform>
                        </ImageBrush.Transform>
```

Transforms to animate the image at regular intervals by changing the X and Y :)

Comment: Thanks for this post but I already knew ImageTools, and I'm planning to use it, but first I have to generate the GIF file :) I'm also almost sure that it's impossible to generate a GIF from a WP application due to device limitations but I need a confirmation from someone who is really sure about it

Comment: No one has i guess really tried. Since so much animating features are there I guess creating a gif file in wp is a rare scenario. You can wait for a Proper answer :-) . But can i know what will be the purpose of the gif. As much I know ImageTools help t display gif in win ph. So can you please tell me what you are planning for. Not the entire scenario but an idea maybe :-)

Answer (score 1):

In fact there is a very interesting way to create animated GIF. It is from VB6 days.
Just create every frame as separate GIF file with same color palette (this is the tricky part). strip GIF header from files except first file and then concatenate them with following magic `0x0021F9`.

Animated GIF format is actually an extension to the GIF format so, application does not understand animated GIF can still be able to display first frame. As far as I remember that each frame can have its own color table, but I do not remember how.

The real trick is to create series of images sharing same color palette, which I haven't done it before. I just used this to load animated GIFs.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to do it by yourself? GIF format now is free, so if you need only to create GIF files, you can just implement specification or only part of it.

http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt

Comment: Yes, I already thought about that. If I really get no fine answer, I'll try to do this by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

I will suggest you one post that shows that how to display a GIF formatted pictures or Animated pictures in windows phone.

Please Refer this link.

> **[Show OR Create the GIF kind Images in windows phone.](http://dotnetternikhil.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/display-gif-or-animated-images-in-windows-phone/)**

This shows that there is like a GIF image but actually there is not a GIF but its a multiple jpeg files Array.

I hope you get the Solution.
Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for this link but it doesn't really help me. This tutorial is about having a tip to show an animated image inside a Windows Phone app... I want to create it. Showing is not a problem, but the final goal of my project is to get a raw gif file as output

Comment: ok.
for your Reference. please see this link [Display Gif images in windows phone Application.](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/how-to-display-gif-images-in-a-windows-phone-application/)